# If $|a_{ij}| \leq L$ for all $i,j$, then $\| A \| \leq L\,$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, matrix-norms

This is my attempt:
Let $A \in M(n, \mathbb R)$, $v \in \mathbb R^n$.
Note that $\| A \| = \sup\limits_{v, \|v\| \leq 1} \|Av\|$.
I may assume WLOG that $\|v\| = 1$.
Take any $v \in \mathbb R^n$. Then, $Av = y$, where $y_i = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_{ij}v_j$.
Then,
\begin{align*}
\|y\|^2 &= \Big(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_{1j}v_j\Big)^2 + \cdots + \Big(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_{nj}v_j\Big)^2 \\
&\leq\Big(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{1j}^2\Big) \cdot \sum_{j=1}^n v_j^2 + \cdots + \Big(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{nj}^2\Big) \cdot \sum_{j=1}^n v_j^2 \quad \text{(by Cauchy-Schwarz)}\\
&\leq\sum_{j=1}^n a_{1j}^2 + \cdots + \sum_{j=1}^n a_{nj}^2 \\
&= nL^2 + \cdots +nL^2 \\
&= (nL)^2
\end{align*}
Hence, $\|A\| \leq nL$. However, my lecture notes state that $\|A\| \leq L$, and I am wondering what should be done to achieve that inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is answered with a **No**.

Please calculate the norm of $\begin{pmatrix}1 &1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. Or consider its action on the vector $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\1\end{pmatrix}$.

A symmetric or self-adjoint example would be the orthogonal projection
$\begin{pmatrix}0.5 &0.5\\ 0.5 & 0.5\end{pmatrix}$ which turns into
$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ upon diagonalisation.

Comment: I see. Taking $(1/\sqrt 2, 1/\sqrt 2)$ already gives a counterexample. Thanks!